ASP.NET MVC config transformations not applying to project.dll.config
I have recently set up a transformation for new configuration profile, named Local, with an output directory of bin\. A new file name Web.Local.config was introduced into the project named Project1.
This file has a transformation of SetAttribute on a connection string as follows:
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=potato;Initial Catalog=potato;Integrated Security=false;user Id=potatouser;password=" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

I'm debugging locally with IISExpress, and can see that during debug time that its sourcing configs from Project1.dll.config, which has the untransformed value. I need the transformed value. Interestingly bin\web.config has the correct attribute for DefaultConnection.
How do I get the transformations to apply to all .config files, and not just the web.config?

Looks like this isn't supported in this scenario by default. Had to add and configure SlowCheetah for this, and then had follow this answer too
